# Table with sticky header. Last column in header is too wide compared to the table

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make a table with a sticky header. I'm almost there but, for some reason the last column in the header have around 2px more width then it should compared to the table. If you run the code below you will see the date column's edge is sticking a little bit outside the table border. Everything else lines up perfectly.

Any suggestion to how I can fix this?

```css
*,
*::before,
*::after {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: inherit;
}

html {
  font-size: 62.5%;
}

body {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 90vw;
  max-width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  min-height: 100vh;
  max-height: 100%;
}

.table {
  border-spacing: 0;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
  table-layout: fixed;
}

.table__wrapper {
  overflow: auto;
  white-space: nowrap;
  width: 100%;
  height: 70vh;
  display: block;
}

.table__sticky {
  position: relative;
}

.table__header {
  top: -0.1rem;
  position: absolute;
  padding: 0.8rem;
  border: 1px solid #43484d;
  box-shadow: inset 0 3.4rem 0 -1.7rem #2d3338;
  background-color: #22262a;
  color: #fff;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 1.4rem;
}

.table__header:hover {
  box-shadow: inset 0 3.4rem 0 -1.7rem #43484d;
  background-color: #2d3338;
}

.table thead th {
  padding: 1.5rem 0;
}

.table td {
  border: 1px solid #959595;
  padding: 0.5rem;
  font-size: 1.3rem;
  text-align: center;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}

.table tbody:hover td {
  color: transparent;
  text-shadow: 0 0 0.3rem #aaa;
}

.table tbody:hover tr:hover td {
  color: #363636;
  text-shadow: none;
}

.table tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #eff1f2;
}

.table .row_width_5 {
  width: 5%;
}

.table .row_width_10 {
  width: 10%;
}

.table .row_width_15 {
  width: 15%;
}

.table .row_width_20 {
  width: 20%;
}

.table .row_width_30 {
  width: 30%;
}

.table .row_width_40 {
  width: 40%;
}

.table .row_width_50 {
  width: 50%;
}

.table .row_width_60 {
  width: 60%;
}

.table .row_width_70 {
  width: 70%;
}

.table .row_width_80 {
  width: 80%;
}

.table .row_width_90 {
  width: 90%;
}

.table .row_width_100 {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="table__sticky">
  <div class="table__wrapper">
    <table class="table">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th class="row_width_5">
            <div class="table__header row_width_5">
              Id
            </div>
          </th>
          <th class="row_width_10">
            <div class="table__header row_width_10">
              User (id)
            </div>
          </th>
          <th class="row_width_10">
            <div class="table__header row_width_10">
              Ip
            </div>
          </th>
          <th class="row_width_20">
            <div class="table__header row_width_20">
              Referrer
            </div>
          </th>
          <th class="row_width_10">
            <div class="table__header row_width_10">
              Browser
            </div>
          </th>
          <th class="row_width_10">
            <div class="table__header row_width_10">
              Platform
            </div>
          </th>
          <th class="row_width_20">
            <div class="table__header row_width_20">
              Page
            </div>
          </th>
          <th class="row_width_15">
            <div class="table__header row_width_15">
              Date
            </div>
          </th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>6228</td>
          <td>N/A (0)</td>
          <td>111.111.111.111</td>
          <td>http://www.rajohan.no/</td>
          <td>Chrome</td>
          <td>macOS</td>
          <td>N/A</td>
          <td>2018-06-19 14:30:06</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>6228</td>
          <td>N/A (0)</td>
          <td>111.111.111.111</td>
          <td>http://www.rajohan.no/</td>
          <td>Chrome</td>
          <td>macOS</td>
          <td>N/A</td>
          <td>2018-06-19 14:30:06</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>6228</td>
          <td>N/A (0)</td>
          <td>111.111.111.111</td>
          <td>http://www.rajohan.no/</td>
          <td>Chrome</td>
          <td>macOS</td>
          <td>N/A</td>
          <td>2018-06-19 14:30:06</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>6228</td>
          <td>N/A (0)</td>
          <td>111.111.111.111</td>
          <td>http://www.rajohan.no/</td>
          <td>Chrome</td>
          <td>macOS</td>
          <td>N/A</td>
          <td>2018-06-19 14:30:06</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>6228</td>
          <td>N/A (0)</td>
          <td>111.111.111.111</td>
          <td>http://www.rajohan.no/</td>
          <td>Chrome</td>
          <td>macOS</td>
          <td>N/A</td>
          <td>2018-06-19 14:30:06</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>6228</td>
          <td>N/A (0)</td>
          <td>111.111.111.111</td>
          <td>http://www.rajohan.no/</td>
          <td>Chrome</td>
          <td>macOS</td>
          <td>N/A</td>
          <td>2018-06-19 14:30:06</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>6228</td>
          <td>N/A (0)</td>
          <td>111.111.111.111</td>
          <td>http://www.rajohan.no/</td>
          <td>Chrome</td>
          <td>macOS</td>
          <td>N/A</td>
          <td>2018-06-19 14:30:06</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>6228</td>
          <td>N/A (0)</td>
          <td>111.111.111.111</td>
          <td>http://www.rajohan.no/</td>
          <td>Chrome</td>
          <td>macOS</td>
          <td>N/A</td>
          <td>2018-06-19 14:30:06</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>6228</td>
          <td>N/A (0)</td>
          <td>111.111.111.111</td>
          <td>http://www.rajohan.no/</td>
          <td>Chrome</td>
          <td>macOS</td>
          <td>N/A</td>
          <td>2018-06-19 14:30:06</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>6228</td>
          <td>N/A (0)</td>
          <td>111.111.111.111</td>
          <td>http://www.rajohan.no/</td>
          <td>Chrome</td>
          <td>macOS</td>
          <td>N/A</td>
          <td>2018-06-19 14:30:06</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>6228</td>
          <td>N/A (0)</td>
          <td>111.111.111.111</td>
          <td>http://www.rajohan.no/</td>
          <td>Chrome</td>
          <td>macOS</td>
          <td>N/A</td>
          <td>2018-06-19 14:30:06</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>6228</td>
          <td>N/A (0)</td>
          <td>111.111.111.111</td>
          <td>http://www.rajohan.no/</td>
          <td>Chrome</td>
          <td>macOS</td>
          <td>N/A</td>
          <td>2018-06-19 14:30:06</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>6228</td>
          <td>N/A (0)</td>
          <td>111.111.111.111</td>
          <td>http://www.rajohan.no/</td>
          <td>Chrome</td>
          <td>macOS</td>
          <td>N/A</td>
          <td>2018-06-19 14:30:06</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>6228</td>
          <td>N/A (0)</td>
          <td>111.111.111.111</td>
          <td>http://www.rajohan.no/</td>
          <td>Chrome</td>
          <td>macOS</td>
          <td>N/A</td>
          <td>2018-06-19 14:30:06</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>6228</td>
          <td>N/A (0)</td>
          <td>111.111.111.111</td>
          <td>http://www.rajohan.no/</td>
          <td>Chrome</td>
          <td>macOS</td>
          <td>N/A</td>
          <td>2018-06-19 14:30:06</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>6228</td>
          <td>N/A (0)</td>
          <td>111.111.111.111</td>
          <td>http://www.rajohan.no/</td>
          <td>Chrome</td>
          <td>macOS</td>
          <td>N/A</td>
          <td>2018-06-19 14:30:06</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>6228</td>
          <td>N/A (0)</td>
          <td>111.111.111.111</td>
          <td>http://www.rajohan.no/</td>
          <td>Chrome</td>
          <td>macOS</td>
          <td>N/A</td>
          <td>2018-06-19 14:30:06</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>6228</td>
          <td>N/A (0)</td>
          <td>111.111.111.111</td>
          <td>http://www.rajohan.no/</td>
          <td>Chrome</td>
          <td>macOS</td>
          <td>N/A</td>
          <td>2018-06-19 14:30:06</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>6228</td>
          <td>N/A (0)</td>
          <td>111.111.111.111</td>
          <td>http://www.rajohan.no/</td>
          <td>Chrome</td>
          <td>macOS</td>
          <td>N/A</td>
          <td>2018-06-19 14:30:06</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>6228</td>
          <td>N/A (0)</td>
          <td>111.111.111.111</td>
          <td>http://www.rajohan.no/</td>
          <td>Chrome</td>
          <td>macOS</td>
          <td>N/A</td>
          <td>2018-06-19 14:30:06</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>6228</td>
          <td>N/A (0)</td>
          <td>111.111.111.111</td>
          <td>http://www.rajohan.no/</td>
          <td>Chrome</td>
          <td>macOS</td>
          <td>N/A</td>
          <td>2018-06-19 14:30:06</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>6228</td>
          <td>N/A (0)</td>
          <td>111.111.111.111</td>
          <td>http://www.rajohan.no/</td>
          <td>Chrome</td>
          <td>macOS</td>
          <td>N/A</td>
          <td>2018-06-19 14:30:06</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>6228</td>
          <td>N/A (0)</td>
          <td>111.111.111.111</td>
          <td>http://www.rajohan.no/</td>
          <td>Chrome</td>
          <td>macOS</td>
          <td>N/A</td>
          <td>2018-06-19 14:30:06</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>6228</td>
          <td>N/A (0)</td>
          <td>111.111.111.111</td>
          <td>http://www.rajohan.no/</td>
          <td>Chrome</td>
          <td>macOS</td>
          <td>N/A</td>
          <td>2018-06-19 14:30:06</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>6228</td>
          <td>N/A (0)</td>
          <td>111.111.111.111</td>
          <td>http://www.rajohan.no/</td>
          <td>Chrome</td>
          <td>macOS</td>
          <td>N/A</td>
          <td>2018-06-19 14:30:06</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>6228</td>
          <td>N/A (0)</td>
          <td>111.111.111.111</td>
          <td>http://www.rajohan.no/</td>
          <td>Chrome</td>
          <td>macOS</td>
          <td>N/A</td>
          <td>2018-06-19 14:30:06</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>6228</td>
          <td>N/A (0)</td>
          <td>111.111.111.111</td>
          <td>http://www.rajohan.no/</td>
          <td>Chrome</td>
          <td>macOS</td>
          <td>N/A</td>
          <td>2018-06-19 14:30:06</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>6228</td>
          <td>N/A (0)</td>
          <td>111.111.111.111</td>
          <td>http://www.rajohan.no/</td>
          <td>Chrome</td>
          <td>macOS</td>
          <td>N/A</td>
          <td>2018-06-19 14:30:06</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>6228</td>
          <td>N/A (0)</td>
          <td>111.111.111.111</td>
          <td>http://www.rajohan.no/</td>
          <td>Chrome</td>
          <td>macOS</td>
          <td>N/A</td>
          <td>2018-06-19 14:30:06</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>6228</td>
          <td>N/A (0)</td>
          <td>111.111.111.111</td>
          <td>http://www.rajohan.no/</td>
          <td>Chrome</td>
          <td>macOS</td>
          <td>N/A</td>
          <td>2018-06-19 14:30:06</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>6228</td>
          <td>N/A (0)</td>
          <td>111.111.111.111</td>
          <td>http://www.rajohan.no/</td>
          <td>Chrome</td>
          <td>macOS</td>
          <td>N/A</td>
          <td>2018-06-19 14:30:06</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>6228</td>
          <td>N/A (0)</td>
          <td>111.111.111.111</td>
          <td>http://www.rajohan.no/</td>
          <td>Chrome</td>
          <td>macOS</td>
          <td>N/A</td>
          <td>2018-06-19 14:30:06</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this by using `position: sticky` on the `th` elements, instead of using `position: absolute` and "cheating" with divs inside the `th` elements. Everything is working perfectly now. Working code below.

```css
*,
*::before,
*::after {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: inherit;
}

html {
  font-size: 62.5%;
}

body {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 90vw;
  max-width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  min-height: 100vh;
  max-height: 100%;
}

.table {
  border-spacing: 0;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
}

.table__wrapper {
  overflow-x: auto;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  white-space: nowrap;
  width: 100%;
  height: 70vh;
  display: block;
}

.table__top__overlay {
  min-height: 1rem;
  min-width: 100%;
  background-color: #fff;
  z-index: 100;
  position: relative;
  margin-bottom: -0.6px;
}

.table thead tr th {
  position: sticky;
  position: -webkit-sticky;
  top: 0;
  padding: 0.8rem;
  border: 1px solid #43484d;
  box-shadow: inset 0 3.4rem 0 -1.7rem #2d3338;
  background-color: #22262a;
  color: #fff;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 1.4rem;
}

.table thead tr th:hover {
  box-shadow: inset 0 3.4rem 0 -1.7rem #43484d;
  background-color: #2d3338;
}

.table td {
  border: 1px solid #43484d;
  padding: 0.5rem;
  font-size: 1.3rem;
  text-align: center;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}

.table tbody:hover td {
  color: transparent;
  text-shadow: 0 0 0.3rem #aaa;
}

.table tbody:hover tr:hover td {
  color: #363636;
  text-shadow: none;
}

.table tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #eff1f2;
}

.table .row_width_5 {
  width: 5%;
}

.table .row_width_10 {
  width: 10%;
}

.table .row_width_15 {
  width: 15%;
}

.table .row_width_20 {
  width: 20%;
}

.table .row_width_25 {
  width: 25%;
}

.table .row_width_30 {
  width: 30%;
}

.table .row_width_35 {
  width: 35%;
}

.table .row_width_40 {
  width: 40%;
}

.table .row_width_45 {
  width: 45%;
}

.table .row_width_50 {
  width: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="table__top__overlay">
</div>
<div class="table__wrapper">
  <table class="table">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th class="row_width_5">
          Id
        </th>
        <th class="row_width_10">
          User (id)
        </th>
        <th class="row_width_10">
          Ip
        </th>
        <th class="row_width_20">
          Referrer
        </th>
        <th class="row_width_10">
          Browser
        </th>
        <th class="row_width_10">
          Platform
        </th>
        <th class="row_width_20">
          Page
        </th>
        <th class="row_width_15">
          Date
        </th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>6228</td>
        <td>N/A (0)</td>
        <td>111.111.111.111</td>
        <td>http://www.rajohan.no/</td>
        <td>Chrome</td>
        <td>macOS</td>
        <td>N/A</td>
        <td>2018-06-19 14:30:06</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>6227</td>
        <td>N/A (0)</td>
        <td>111.111.111.111</td>
        <td>N/A</td>
        <td>IE</td>
        <td>Win10</td>
        <td>N/A</td>
        <td>2018-06-19 13:48:48</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>6226</td>
        <td>N/A (0)</td>
        <td>111.111.111.111</td>
        <td>http://www.rajohan.org/</td>
        <td>Chrome</td>
        <td>macOS</td>
        <td>N/A</td>
        <td>2018-06-19 12:12:57</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>6225</td>
        <td>N/A (0)</td>
        <td>111.111.111.111</td>
        <td>N/A</td>
        <td>Python-urllib</td>
        <td>unknown</td>
        <td>N/A</td>
        <td>2018-06-19 11:29:48</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>6224</td>
        <td>N/A (0)</td>
        <td>111.111.111.111</td>
        <td>N/A</td>
        <td>Baiduspider</td>
        <td>unknown</td>
        <td>N/A</td>
        <td>2018-06-19 11:12:39</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>6223</td>
        <td>N/A (0)</td>
        <td>111.111.111.111</td>
        <td>N/A</td>
        <td>Applebot</td>
        <td>MacOSX</td>
        <td>/newsletter/</td>
        <td>2018-06-19 09:56:43</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>6222</td>
        <td>N/A (0)</td>
        <td>111.111.111.111</td>
        <td>http://172.104.225.59:80/</td>
        <td>Default Browser</td>
        <td>unknown</td>
        <td>N/A</td>
        <td>2018-06-19 08:54:54</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>6221</td>
        <td>N/A (0)</td>
        <td>111.111.111.111</td>
        <td>N/A</td>
        <td>N/A</td>
        <td>N/A</td>
        <td>/error.html</td>
        <td>2018-06-19 07:53:54</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>6220</td>
        <td>N/A (0)</td>
        <td>111.111.111.111</td>
        <td>N/A</td>
        <td>N/A</td>
        <td>N/A</td>
        <td>N/A</td>
        <td>2018-06-19 07:53:53</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>6220</td>
        <td>N/A (0)</td>
        <td>111.111.111.111</td>
        <td>N/A</td>
        <td>N/A</td>
        <td>N/A</td>
        <td>N/A</td>
        <td>2018-06-19 07:53:53</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>6220</td>
        <td>N/A (0)</td>
        <td>111.111.111.111</td>
        <td>N/A</td>
        <td>N/A</td>
        <td>N/A</td>
        <td>N/A</td>
        <td>2018-06-19 07:53:53</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>6220</td>
        <td>N/A (0)</td>
        <td>111.111.111.111</td>
        <td>N/A</td>
        <td>N/A</td>
        <td>N/A</td>
        <td>N/A</td>
        <td>2018-06-19 07:53:53</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>6220</td>
        <td>N/A (0)</td>
        <td>111.111.111.111</td>
        <td>N/A</td>
        <td>N/A</td>
        <td>N/A</td>
        <td>N/A</td>
        <td>2018-06-19 07:53:53</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>6220</td>
        <td>N/A (0)</td>
        <td>111.111.111.111</td>
        <td>N/A</td>
        <td>N/A</td>
        <td>N/A</td>
        <td>N/A</td>
        <td>2018-06-19 07:53:53</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>6219</td>
        <td>N/A (0)</td>
        <td>111.111.111.111</td>
        <td>N/A</td>
        <td>Google Bot</td>
        <td>unknown</td>
        <td>N/A</td>
        <td>2018-06-19 07:05:55</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>6218</td>
        <td>N/A (0)</td>
        <td>111.111.111.111</td>
        <td>N/A</td>
        <td>Google Bot</td>
        <td>Android</td>
        <td>N/A</td>
        <td>2018-06-19 06:20:15</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>6217</td>
        <td>N/A (0)</td>
        <td>111.111.111.111</td>
        <td>N/A</td>
        <td>Google Bot</td>
        <td>unknown</td>
        <td>N/A</td>
        <td>2018-06-19 05:24:28</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>6216</td>
        <td>N/A (0)</td>
        <td>111.111.111.111</td>
        <td>N/A</td>
        <td>Chrome</td>
        <td>MacOSX</td>
        <td>N/A</td>
        <td>2018-06-19 04:43:10</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>6215</td>
        <td>N/A (0)</td>
        <td>111.111.111.111</td>
        <td>N/A</td>
        <td>Applebot</td>
        <td>MacOSX</td>
        <td>/register/</td>
        <td>2018-06-19 03:55:35</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>6214</td>
        <td>N/A (0)</td>
        <td>111.111.111.111</td>
        <td>N/A</td>
        <td>Baiduspider</td>
        <td>unknown</td>
        <td>N/A</td>
        <td>2018-06-19 03:45:36</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>6213</td>
        <td>N/A (0)</td>
        <td>111.111.111.111</td>
        <td>N/A</td>
        <td>Google Bot</td>
        <td>unknown</td>
        <td>N/A</td>
        <td>2018-06-19 02:20:35</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>6214</td>
        <td>N/A (0)</td>
        <td>111.111.111.111</td>
        <td>N/A</td>
        <td>Baiduspider</td>
        <td>unknown</td>
        <td>N/A</td>
        <td>2018-06-19 03:45:36</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>6213</td>
        <td>N/A (0)</td>
        <td>111.111.111.111</td>
        <td>N/A</td>
        <td>Google Bot</td>
        <td>unknown</td>
        <td>N/A</td>
        <td>2018-06-19 02:20:35</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>6214</td>
        <td>N/A (0)</td>
        <td>111.111.111.111</td>
        <td>N/A</td>
        <td>Baiduspider</td>
        <td>unknown</td>
        <td>N/A</td>
        <td>2018-06-19 03:45:36</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>6213</td>
        <td>N/A (0)</td>
        <td>111.111.111.111</td>
        <td>N/A</td>
        <td>Google Bot</td>
        <td>unknown</td>
        <td>N/A</td>
        <td>2018-06-19 02:20:35</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>6214</td>
        <td>N/A (0)</td>
        <td>111.111.111.111</td>
        <td>N/A</td>
        <td>Baiduspider</td>
        <td>unknown</td>
        <td>N/A</td>
        <td>2018-06-19 03:45:36</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>6213</td>
        <td>N/A (0)</td>
        <td>111.111.111.111</td>
        <td>N/A</td>
        <td>Google Bot</td>
        <td>unknown</td>
        <td>N/A</td>
        <td>2018-06-19 02:20:35</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>6214</td>
        <td>N/A (0)</td>
        <td>111.111.111.111</td>
        <td>N/A</td>
        <td>Baiduspider</td>
        <td>unknown</td>
        <td>N/A</td>
        <td>2018-06-19 03:45:36</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>6213</td>
        <td>N/A (0)</td>
        <td>111.111.111.111</td>
        <td>N/A</td>
        <td>Google Bot</td>
        <td>unknown</td>
        <td>N/A</td>
        <td>2018-06-19 02:20:35</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems moving `height` and `overflow` from `.table__wrapper` to `.table__sticky` solves your problem.

```
.table__sticky {
    position: relative;
    height: 70vh;
    overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

[image: img]

Comment: Yeah looks like that fixes it. But, then it appars a 1px white gap between the header columns ID and USER (ID). Something is wired with the border on the header. If i do border-right and not just border in .table_header only the first half of the columns get a border on the right